# AVAssetWriterInput - black screen, 46 hours long

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avasset

I'm trying to take an AVCaptureSession and encode to mp4. It seems like this should be straightforward, and I'm trying to encode a single 960x540 video stream; I'm not worried about audio for the purpose of this issue.

When I run the following code and grab `out2.mp4` out of the documents container with Xcode, I get a black screen in quicktime and the duration is 46 hours long. At least the resolution looks right. Here's output from `ffmpeg -i out2.mp4`

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2015-11-18 01:25:55
  Duration: 46:43:04.21, start: 168178.671667, bitrate: 0 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 960x540, 1860 kb/s, 27.65 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-18 01:25:55
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
```

Why can't I append sample buffers to the `AVAssetWriterInput` in this scenario?

```
var videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.startStream()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "swapSegment", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func swapSegment() {
    assetWriter?.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler(){
        print("File written")
    }
    videoInput = nil
}

func pathForOutput() -> String {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    if let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first {
        let fileUrl = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("out1.mp4")
        return fileUrl.path!
    }
    return ""
}

func startStream() {
    assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.pathForOutput()), fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4)

    let videoSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey: 960, AVVideoHeightKey: 540]
    videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
    videoInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    assetWriter?.addInput(videoInput!)
    assetWriter!.startWriting()
    assetWriter!.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)

    let videoHelper = VideoHelper()
    videoHelper.delegate = self
    videoHelper.startSession()
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if let videoOutput = captureOutput as? AVCaptureVideoDataOutput {
        videoInput?.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your presentation times are not relative to your sourceTime (`kCMTimeZero`). You could use the first buffer presentation time stamp as the source time.

p.s. maybe 46hrs is approximately your device uptime

Comment: Even if with if `!sessionStarted {
            sessionStarted = true
            assetWriter!.startSessionAtSourceTime(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer))
        }`, I get a duration of 46 hours.

Comment: Never mind, it works! Make sure to delete the file you're writing to before trying to write to it.